# FetchedResultsController: sorting through relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sorting, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using default Apple docs boilerplate code to update a tableview on FRC events. This is the request I'm using:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contactWish != NULL"];

NSSortDescriptor *sort2 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"contactWish.nextReminder.remindDate" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sort2];

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;
```

The problem is that if a `contactWish.nextReminder.remindDate` is updated the tableview never re-sorts its items. Everything else works. Is this expected behavior? Can't I make the FRC keep track of attributes across relationships somehow? I've tried several ways, none which worked.

Comment: Do you change the contactWish...? If so you could try [table reloadData]

Comment: Unfortunately reloadData doesn't work. It only pulls the wrongly sorted items from the FRC. I'm not making changes to the contactWish object or to that relationship.